# Facebook mobile login and server-side validation

Tags: android, facebook, rest, security, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a mobile app that has an integrated Facebook login (using the fb android sdk). I also have a server that has some rest endpoints on it that I would like to secure. I have been looking around for days trying to find the best solution (reading articles on the dev site: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security, other stackoverflow posts) but I am not quite sure what is the best solution.

At the moment I have the following setup in place:

1. User logs in on the app using Facebook (mobile android sdk).
2. When requesting a resource from a rest endpoint the token will be added as a header.
3. On the server side I validate the token using the fb debug_token endpoint (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/debug_token)
4. If the validation is successful I allow my rest resource to be 'called'

As you can see I will have do my own request to Facebook (server side) for every request I receive. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Verify the token once, and then store the result in your session.

Comment: So I should keep the result from the token debug stored in a database?

Comment: Not unless you’re extending the token, because it will only be valid for about two hours anyway.

Comment: "Mobile apps that use Facebook's iOS and Android SDKs get long-lived tokens by default." https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens.

Comment: Alright. Still, the token could have become invalid by the next time the user uses your app … so I think storing the debug result makes more sense on a per-session basis.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook uses OAuth, and with this protocol you should have in the response headers or body an expiry time attribute associed with the token.

So you can store wherever you want the tuple (token, token_expiry) to bypass the request to facebook most of the time.

In fact you should have a response with those attributes:

```
{
"access_token": <access-token>,
 "token_type":<type>,
 "expires_in":<seconds-til-expiration>
}
```

Comment: So are saying that I should send this information over and store it on my server?

Comment: Yes you can do that (in memory and/or long live persistency) to manage the authentication across all the user requests